# Photoshop scripting (.jsx): push string into an Array only if it doesn't exist there yet

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsx, photoshop-script

I have a unique signature being generated for each iteration, which I want to eventually save on a .txt file.

My signature is quite simple, using 0-9 and A-Z, being 14 chars long.

I want to push it to an Array only if that Array doesn't contain it yet. Here is what I tried to do:

```
var uniqueSignature = []

do {
    var uniqueSignature = generateSignature()
    if (!signatureArray.includes(uniqueSignature)){ //checks if the Array does not contain the signature.
        signatureArray.push(uniqueSignature) //pushes the signature into the array.
    }
} while (!signatureArray.includes(uniqueSignature)) //Keep doing so until the signature can be inserted (meaning is unique)

function generateSignature(){
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    var signatureLength = 14
    var genSignature = ""
    for (var i = 0; i <= signatureLength; i++) {
        var randomChars = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)
        genSignature += chars.substring(randomChars, randomChars +1)
    }
    currentSignature = genSignature 
}

//[... eventually will write the array to a .txt files]
```

When I try to run it on Adobe Photoshop > Browse > Load script, I get this error:
[image]

I've also tried to replace `.includes` for `.indexOf`, pushing it only if `signatureArray.indexOf(uniqueSignature) == -1`, but got the same error.

Any ideas? I know that jsx/Photoshop has some limitations when it comes to code (like it won't let me use ${var} and such). Is that the thing here?

If so, is there any other way for me to achieve this push after verification?

Comment: Photoshop code is limiting, it actually uses ECMAscript ver 3. Whilst you get fooled into thinking it's JavaScript; it's actually a limited subset of that - and yes, you do have to take the long road sometimes.

Comment: @GhoulFool thank you for the enlightenment; I had no idea it was that obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to bypass this by working with a String instead of an Array:

```
var currentSignature
var z = 0

do {
    generateSignature()
    
    if (signatureString.indexOf(currentSignature) == -1){
        signatureString = signatureString + currentSignature + '\n'
        z = 1
    }
} while (z = 0)
```

In the future, I can pass a `.join('\n')` if I need to convert the string (file content) into an Array again.